# Interval of convergence for $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n+1}x^{n}}{n^{2}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I've been asked to find the interval of convergence the following series.
$$x-\dfrac{x^2}{4} +\dfrac{x^3}{9}-\dfrac{x^4}{16} ...$$

Though I solved it, I'm not sure of my answer.

**Here's my work:**

Expressing the series in series notation,
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n+1}x^{n}}{n^{2}}$$

Using ratio test,

$$\left|\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n+2}x^{n + 1}}{(n+1)^{2}}\cdot \frac{n^2}{\left(-1\right)^{n+1}x^{n}}\right| < 1$$

$$\left|\lim_{n\to\infty} (-x) \left(\dfrac{n}{n+1}\right)^2\right| < 1$$

$$\left| - x\right| < 1$$

$$\left|x\right| < 1$$

$$- 1  < x < 1$$

Is there anything wrong with my method?

Comment: Your work looks correct. Well done!

Comment: See Cauchy–Hadamard theorem.

Comment: You must also check the endpoints.  The ratio test never works at the endpoints  but the formula is simpler.

Comment: Well, it seems that we are looking to real values for $x$. There is some "tacit trap" in the way the question asks for an "interval of convergence". Of course, $(-1/2, 1/2)$ is also an interval of convergence. But tacitly, the question asks for the maximal one. In this case, it is maybe good to think also about the points $-1$ and $+1$, since there may be some bigger interval (like $[-1,+1)$ or so) where the given power series converges.

Comment: Thank you guys, I appreciate you for putting in your time, checking my solution, and for your suggestions.